# Updating kernel but not packages

Tags: fedora, kernel, rpm

I need to update the kernel from version 2.6.30 to 2.6.37. I'm going to just compile the kernel and kernel modules for this architecture and boot it. But also there are a lot of packages installed, and I would like to know if I have to update all of them also for the newer kernel, or can I update only some of them which I need, and keep old versions of other packages?(I'm asking since that computer doesn't have internet connection and I would have to do that manually). I know that kernel headers are backward compatible and so on but I'm still not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2.6.37 is quite old, so you should really be asking yourself if that's what you want. The age also means that many people have probably forgotten how much change happened at that time (I know I have), but those versions are close enough, and both 2.6, so I guess there were no API/ABI-changes, and that means it should be safe to upgrade the kernel and nothing else. But I'm not promising anything.

Comment: As far as I could find from a quick search, Fedora 13 had 2.6.33 so you must be quite far behind.

Comment: Yes I know it's an old release but it's enough for tasks which that machine performs. Thanks for the answer, probably I will have just  to try and see if everything works in a proper way :)

Comment: @goodking If the tasks the machine performs include connecting to the Internet, please update to a newer release. There are many known, critical security vulnerabilities that do not have fixes in F13 but which are corrected in current releases.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, the golden rule of kernel development is “never break userspace”. Thus you can upgrade the kernel and all applications should work. But in practice, *should* does not always equal *does*. This especially applies to ancient kernel versions though; I can't think of a real breaking change since the 2.4 series.

The main thing that generally *will* not work is any third-party kernel module. Unlike kernel-user interfaces, the kernel-kernel interfaces that modules use can and often do change from version to version, not only at the binary level but also at the source level. If you have any third-party kernel modules and you upgrade your kernel then you may need to obtain matching versions of the kernel module, if they exist.

While end-user applications are usually safe, some administration or hardware-related tools depend on kernel interfaces that are declared to be unstable. In particular, the organization of files in `/sys` has changed over its lifetime, and not all programs access it through the interfaces that remained stable. The `/proc` interfaces are more stable, but there have been changes there in the past; for example the firewall interfaces changed in a backward-incompatible way in 2.2 (`ipfwadm` → `ipchains`) and again in 2.4 (`ipchains` → `iptables`) (but not since then).

Another thing that might change is the default naming of entries in `/dev` (for example because some disk drivers changed from `hd?` to `sd?`). This can be avoided or papered over via udev.

Answer (score 1):

This is ancient, ancient. Jurassic for [Fedora](https://www.fedoraproject.org). I'd investigate updating the whole distribution to Fedora 23 (24 is scheduled for June or so, so 23 has something like a year still before being dropped). As long as the "lots of packages" you have installed are from the distribution, you should be fine. But you will probably need to reinstall, and install your packages on top. There have been *huge* changes since kernel 2.6.x, not only kernel-side, also in userland.

If the one year or so lifetime of Fedora is too fast for you, you can try [CentOS](https://www.centos.org) (also RPM based, a clone of sorts of [Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/linux-platforms/enterprise-linux), thus quite close in handling). But being enterprisey, the software selection is much more limited. You might consider adding [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) for extra packages.

If this is an old, limited machine, you'd better look e.g. at [DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com) for distributions for old/limited machines.

Comment: Yes this is a pretty limited machine, so anything with higher kernel versions wouldn't work. Thanx for the advice about CentOS, I will consider it.

Comment: @goodking, consider if just upgrading the machine is least costly in the end. Old, unmaintained distributions are calling for trouble (yes, ancient exploits are still being tried) and old machines have a sad propensity to die suddenly without any possibility to get replacement parts, leaving you in the lurch.

Comment: 800 MHz cpu and 512 mb ram (it's an SBC). :)  Maximal kernel version which could work on it is 2.6.39 as I know. But as I said this machine is intended for some limited tasks so it's pretty okay. So far it works pretty stable just need to add some features which are not supported in older kernel.